# How do I convert BrowserRouter react code for nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to conditionally route the user based on whether they are logged in or not which is checked by my global state variable `user`. I'm trying to implement this react code into Next.js but I am getting a document reference error. How would I be able to perform the same logic in this code but having it Next.js oriented? Essentially, I don't want to use `BrowserRouter`.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useAuthContext } from 'hooks/useAuthContext';
import HomePage from './home';
import ProductPage from './product';
import LoginPage from './login';
import SignupPage from './signup';

export default function IndexPage() {
  const { user } = useAuthContext()

  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Routes>
            <Route 
              path="/" 
              element={<HomePage />} 
            />
            <Route 
              path="/login" 
              element={!user ? <LoginPage /> : <Navigate to="/" />} 
            />
            <Route 
              path="/signup" 
              element={!user ? <SignupPage /> : <Navigate to="/" />} 
            />
            <Route 
              path="/product" 
              element={!user ? <ProductPage /> : <Navigate to="/" />} 
            />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can have a conditional rendering logic inside an `AuthContextProvider` in which you check/extract user info and render auth routes/navigate to un-auth routes depending on this info. You'd need a `loading` state or an indeterminant `user` state value to avoid flash of auth content while making this validation, since you are checking this on the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

Nextjs has a file based routing system.
If you want to implement protected routing system then it is preferable to use nextjs middleware. ([https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware](https://middleware))

Answer (score 0):

Next.js solves those complications. As already mentioned, routings are based on directory. You can refer to the next.js document [here](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/navigate-between-pages/pages-in-nextjs).